# ClearScript: Stop converting methods to JavaScript properties

Tags: javascript, c#, clearscript

```
_Engine.Script.test( new { test = 123, cat = "lolcat" } );
```

This outputs the following to JavaScript:

```
{"Equals":{},"GetHashCode":{},"ToString":{},"GetType":{},"test":123,"cat":"lolcat"}
```

As you can see also the **methods** are being converted to Json properties. Is it possible (with as little boilerplate syntax as possible) to only send the properties? Same goes for Expando-like objects.

Below here works, and I can replace a bit of boilerplate with some extension methods, but it would be nice if I can completely get rid of all boilerplate.

```
var js = _Engine.Evaluate( "eval(" + JSONSerializer.Serialize(new { test = 123, cat = "lolcat" }) + ")" );

_Engine.Script.test( js );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using ClearScript's [`PropertyBag`](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Reference/html/T_Microsoft_ClearScript_PropertyBag.htm)? For example,

```
_Engine.Script.test( new PropertyBag { { "test", 123 }, { "cat", "lolcat" } } );
```

Or, if you're using C# 6 or later,

```
_Engine.Script.test( new PropertyBag { ["test"] = 123, ["cat"] = "lolcat" } );
```

Comment: The problem is that my data is coming from other ExpandoObjects from different parts of the code, where they are being used for other means - this means I still need to write a converter for these objects.

Comment: How are you examining the object in JavaScript? Since you're seeing the methods as properties, I'm guessing that you're using [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)?

Comment: I'm using JSON.stringify(obj)

Comment: Hmm, `JSON.stringify` doesn't seem to work with .NET objects at all (at least in the latest ClearScript), so yes, you'll probably have to create native JavaScript objects.